# In Python, how can I iterate through the values of a dictionary when the values are a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary, and it's a little complicated so I'll make a sample:

```
final = {x: [-.5, 1], y: [.75, 2], z: [.25, 3]}
```

with the dictionary "genes", I need to loop through the list associated with each key and:

1. Append a 0 to the list if the second value in the list is more than a given input (which I call p), or a 1 if it's less than p.
2. If the first value is negative, I need to multiply the appended number by -1 to make it a negative number.

Here is the code I have right now (running python 2.7):

```
for k, v in final.iterkeys():
    if v[1] <= p:
        v.append("1")
    else:
        v.append("0")
    if v[0] < 0:
        v[2] *= -1
```

After that, I write only the key (x, y, and z in this case) and the appended number to a csv file. Here's my code for that, if you were wondering:

```
writer = csv.writer(open("result.csv", "wb"))
for k, v in final.iteritems():
    writer.writerow([k, v[2]])
```

As far as I know, that section works. But I could be wrong, and my error is actually there

The expected output for p=2, as in the final outputted csv file, would look like:

```
x, -1
y, 1
z, 0
```

Instead, I'm just getting

```
x, 0
y, 0
z, 0
```

Any idea what's going on? I'm pretty new to programming and python, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `iterkeys` if you want to iterate over the key-value pairs? That's `iteritems`. (Actually, you shouldn't even use `iterkeys` for iterating over the keys, since `for k in d` does that.)

Comment: And why are you appending string `"0"` or `"1"` instead of ints? You're trying to do math with the list items, so you seem to want ints, but it looks like you have a list of strings or mixed data types instead.

Comment: Changed iterkeys to iteritems, and used ints instead of strings. Still getting only 0's in the output

Comment: Probably because `v[0]` and `v[1]` are strings too.

Comment: So should I start off with:

    for k, v in final.iteritems():
        int(v[0:])

and then continue with the rest of the loop?

Comment: No, because that's not going to work for converting things to integers. First, `int` does not modify its input; it returns an integer. If you call `int` on something, you will not find that the thing you called it on has changed. Second, calling `int` on a list will not iterate over the list and convert its elements to integers. It will just fail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are appending a string "0" or "1" and then multiplying it by -1. Try appending the integer 0 or 1, multiplying that, and converting the final value to a string.

```
for v in final.itervalues():
    if v[1] <= p:
        v.append(1)
    else:
        v.append(0)
    if v[0] < 0:
        v[2] *= -1
```

Comment: Alright, do I even need to convert to a string at the end? Or will csv writer write the integer okay?

Comment: It depends on how you want to store it in the dict's list. I'd leave it as numeric. I believe the csv writer will use the repr value of the number.

Comment: Alright, well I tried it both with making v[2] a string and without making v[2] a string, both still outputted only 0's

Comment: After running the above for-loop, `final={'y': [0.75, 2, 1], 'x': [-0.5, 1, -1], 'z': [0.25, 3, 0]}`. What is your value of `final`?

Comment: I get an AtributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You're probably still using `iterkeys` instead of `itervalues`/`iteritems`. Run `final = {'x': [-.5, 1], 'y': [.75, 2], 'z': [.25, 3]}` then run the code in my response.

Comment: nope, I got that error with itervalues as well. Good thought though, because I did forget to change it first